# ASP.NET Dynamic Data - Globalization and Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anybody know how to create a multilingual web application using Dynamic Data and
be able to show any label or button in the correct language upon the selected culture?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `ResourceProviderFactory` to get your localisations from wherever you want. We use a string as a key to look up the localisations:

For instance:

```
<asp:Literal Text="<%$ Resources: DBLanguageProvider, Module/Area/HelpMessage %>" runat="server" />
```